# Spring Security inmemory authentication issue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I am using Spring Security inmemory authentication, but it is not working properly.
It is generating default password but it is not taking the **user and password** I generated in configuration. Below is my controller:

```java
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AppController {

     @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/plain")
     public String sayHello() {
         return "Hello welcome to spring security!!!!";
     }
}
```

And below is my security configuration class:

```java
@Component
@EnableWebSecurity
/*@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity*/
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { 
        org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration.class 
    })
public class SecurityProvider extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {           
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("ramu")
                    .password("password")
                    .roles("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                .withUser("gopal")
                    .password("password")
                    .roles("USER");
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        // ALTHOUGH THIS SEEMS LIKE USELESS CODE,
        // ITS REQUIRED TO PREVENT SPRING BOOT AUTO-CONFIGURATION
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

I also tried by excluding `SecurityAutoconfiguration.class` at main application by using below annonation:

```java
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
public class App {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

But no luck, it is not taking the username and password I configured in my configuration class.

Comment: As git-flo already wrote you have to change `@Component` with `@Configuration` and remove `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.  Also remove `authenticationManagerBean` method and `exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class }`.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your setup, see the code below.

**The WebSecurityConfig (instead of the former `ServiceProvider` component):**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/*").hasRole("ADMIN").and().formLogin();

    }

    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder =
            PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .withUser("ramu")
                .password("password")
                .roles("ADMIN")
            .and()
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
                .withUser("gopal")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }
}
```

**The RestController:**

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AppController {

@RequestMapping(value="/hello",method=RequestMethod.GET,produces="text/plain")
   public String sayHello(){

       return "Hello welcome to spring security!!!!";
   }

}
```

**What I had to change:**

1. `ServiceProvider @Component` -> `WebSecurityConfig @Configuration`
2. I registered a `PasswordEncoder`
3. I reverted all of the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` annotations
4. I reverted the `AuthenticationManager` Bean

I used the spring-parent:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

---

**Solution for `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `1.5.7.RELEASE`:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/*").hasRole("ADMIN").and().formLogin();

    }


    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("ramu")
                .password("password")
                .roles("ADMIN")
            .and()
                .withUser("gopal")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER");
    }}
```

Maybe consider to use a kind of `passwordEncoder` here as well.

Comment: can you please provide me some information about your `spring-boot` and `spring-security` version? In addition I need to see your `application.properties` (or .yaml).

Comment: and please make sure you deleted the `(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class })` annotation in your main-app.

Comment: Below is spring boot parent:     <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  
  <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath></relativePath>
  </parent>

Comment: Spring security is:  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
   </dependency>

Comment: Application.properties:    server.port=9010
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.required=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.connectiontimeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.timeout=5000
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.writetimeout=5000
email.from=sdhrmca@gmail.com

Comment: I also removed (exclude={securityAutoConfiguration.class}), but no luck.

Comment: Can you try to remove the complete application.properties and  check if the behaviour changed?

Comment: The other difference I figured out is the spring version (I use 2.0.4 spring parent instead of 1.5.7)

Comment: I removed application.properties but no luck. But i need application.properties and i have to use Springboot 1.5.7. Can you tell me what is wrong here? is there any issue with springsecurity?

Comment: I added a configuration for spring-boot 1.5.7. For me it worked like a charm. If this still does not fix your problem, I recommend to setup a new project and try it out there. This should at least give you some hints, where your original project is broken.